# Windows - bulk symbolic link files and folders resursively

Tags: windows, batch-file, symlink

I have a folder (say Folder A) which contains many files and folders (those folders also have files inside it).
I want to create symbolic links with each content of the parent folder (Folder A) recursively within a new folder (Say Folder B).

I've been searching for hours and there are many solutions but none of them are working for me. Maybe I am missing something (I don't know batch file scripting). In Linux I could have done that. But I need this in Windows.

In Windows I could have done, `mklink /J "D:\Folder_B" "D:\Folder_A"`, but this will junction the whole folder. I need to keep some files only specific to Folder B.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, this might not be a proper batch file but this is what I did and works!!

```
@ECHO OFF

set source_dir="D:\Folder_A\"
set target_dir="D:\Folder_B\"

FOR /d %%X in (%source_dir%*) DO  (
    mklink /J %target_dir%%%~nX %%X
)

FOR %%I in (%source_dir%*.*) DO (
    mklink %target_dir%%%~nxI %%I
)
```